# Cannot access to local webpage in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I started to learn '[Introduction to Spring MVC](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/springmvc-intro)' course from pluralsight.
When I trying to access http://localhost:8080/FitnessTracker/greeting.html I get `HTTP Status 404`. I have access to `localhost:8080/FitnessTracker` that shows `index.jsp`. In tutorials everything works fine so I'm confused because i did everything same way.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>

<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
```

**servlet-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvchttp:  //www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sergey.controller"/>

<!-- 
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
 -->

 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
 p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.sergey.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping(value ="/greeting")
public String sayHello (Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello World");

    return "hello";
}
}
```

**hello.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>${greeting}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**My directory structure:**

- FitnessTracker

  - src

    - main

      - java

        - com/sergey/controller

          - HelloController.java
      - resources
      - webapp

        - WEB-INF

          - config

            - servlet-config.xml
          - jsp

            - hello.jsp
          - web.xml
        - index.jsp
  - pom.xml

Comment: Is your hello.jsp inside /WEB-INF/jsp/ ?

Comment: Please share directory sturcture

Comment: @geekyprathmesh added directory structure to my post. Sorry cant add picture because of low reputation. Please, help !

Comment: On this picture you have hello.jsp inside config folder instead of jsp folder! Look at your prefix config <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>

Comment: @jgr Sorry, my mistake while editing previous post. It's correct now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear Сергей Сиротинин,

I have tried the same thing.
What i have done is removed

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

tag and also as my jars was of version 3.0 replaced `3.2 with 3.0` in servlet-config.xml

Please try the same.

Comment: Thanks ! replacing jars from 3.2 to 3.0 version really helped. Do yo know why routing doesn't work in 3.2 version ?

Comment: I had jars of version 3.0 might be you are having the same.. What is your spring jar version, Please share.